# Cleaning up a messy Chart.js line chart result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, chart.js

I have the following chart using Chart.js.

[image]

As you can see the result is incredibly messy.

**How would I go about cleaning this up?**

---

I've tried `stepSize` in the `x` axis but it didn't do anything.

```js
var ctx = $("#chart");
   
   var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    
       data: {
     datasets:
     [
      {
       backgroundColor: '#27ae60',
       borderColor: '#27ae60',
       data: [
        {x:'2018-04-06 09:09:09.655699',y:167.96},{x:'2018-04-06 09:11:54.471139',y:177.35},{x:'2018-04-06 10:05:54.898945',y:173.22},{x:'2018-04-06 10:08:55.355812',y:177.30},{x:'2018-04-06 10:12:11.805191',y:180.15},{x:'2018-04-06 10:13:19.715115',y:179.14},{x:'2018-04-06 10:15:05.644111',y:176.00},{x:'2018-04-06 10:46:13.565495',y:156.05},{x:'2018-04-06 11:02:45.523708',y:180.08},{x:'2018-04-06 11:03:33.727033',y:180.56},{x:'2018-04-06 11:04:35.171490',y:179.14},{x:'2018-04-06 11:45:58.156544',y:181.19},{x:'2018-04-06 11:50:39.120997',y:180.23},{x:'2018-04-06 11:51:55.661541',y:180.57},{x:'2018-04-06 11:54:04.882602',y:181.16},{x:'2018-04-06 11:55:00.040104',y:180.06},{x:'2018-04-06 11:56:33.241252',y:180.55},{x:'2018-04-06 11:59:20.307318',y:179.14},{x:'2018-04-06 12:01:40.442655',y:180.57},{x:'2018-04-06 12:05:46.062293',y:180.93},{x:'2018-04-06 12:30:20.836871',y:179.17},{x:'2018-04-06 13:00:21.519024',y:180.04},{x:'2018-04-06 13:30:19.546782',y:180.25},{x:'2018-04-06 14:00:22.271000',y:180.59},{x:'2018-04-06 14:30:21.328425',y:180.60},{x:'2018-04-06 15:00:26.159340',y:180.17},{x:'2018-04-06 15:30:24.866116',y:181.00},{x:'2018-04-06 16:00:24.717159',y:181.03},{x:'2018-04-06 16:30:19.425427',y:181.17},{x:'2018-04-06 17:00:23.965748',y:181.17},{x:'2018-04-06 17:30:21.966713',y:180.22},{x:'2018-04-06 18:00:24.467742',y:180.55},{x:'2018-04-06 18:30:19.554409',y:180.09}       ],
       fill: false,
      },
      {
       backgroundColor: '#2980b9',
       borderColor: '#2980b9',
       data: [
        {x:'2018-04-06 09:09:09.655699',y:182.11},{x:'2018-04-06 09:11:54.471139',y:180.95},{x:'2018-04-06 10:05:54.898945',y:183.27},{x:'2018-04-06 10:08:55.355812',y:182.44},{x:'2018-04-06 10:12:11.805191',y:183.12},{x:'2018-04-06 10:13:19.715115',y:183.14},{x:'2018-04-06 10:15:05.644111',y:182.87},{x:'2018-04-06 10:46:13.565495',y:181.60},{x:'2018-04-06 11:02:45.523708',y:183.19},{x:'2018-04-06 11:03:33.727033',y:182.84},{x:'2018-04-06 11:04:35.171490',y:182.77},{x:'2018-04-06 11:45:58.156544',y:182.47},{x:'2018-04-06 11:50:39.120997',y:182.23},{x:'2018-04-06 11:51:55.661541',y:181.48},{x:'2018-04-06 11:54:04.882602',y:183.43},{x:'2018-04-06 11:55:00.040104',y:183.20},{x:'2018-04-06 11:56:33.241252',y:182.88},{x:'2018-04-06 11:59:20.307318',y:181.19},{x:'2018-04-06 12:01:40.442655',y:182.04},{x:'2018-04-06 12:05:46.062293',y:182.18},{x:'2018-04-06 12:30:20.836871',y:182.82},{x:'2018-04-06 13:00:21.519024',y:182.27},{x:'2018-04-06 13:30:19.546782',y:183.40},{x:'2018-04-06 14:00:22.271000',y:181.61},{x:'2018-04-06 14:30:21.328425',y:182.89},{x:'2018-04-06 15:00:26.159340',y:182.87},{x:'2018-04-06 15:30:24.866116',y:182.99},{x:'2018-04-06 16:00:24.717159',y:182.86},{x:'2018-04-06 16:30:19.425427',y:182.88},{x:'2018-04-06 17:00:23.965748',y:181.96},{x:'2018-04-06 17:30:21.966713',y:181.87},{x:'2018-04-06 18:00:24.467742',y:182.90},{x:'2018-04-06 18:30:19.554409',y:183.07}       ],
       fill: false,
      }  
     ] 
    },
    
    options: {
        responsive: false,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:false
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                   type: 'time',
       time: {
        parser: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
        unit: 'minute',
        displayFormats: {
                           'minute': 'HH:mm',
         'hour': 'HH:mm'
                          }
       },
       ticks: {
        source: 'data'
       }
               }]
        }
    }
         
   });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.0/locale/af.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="chart" width="800" height="450"></canvas>
</body>
</html
```